Autoscroll in FlowLayoutPanel does not work properly, how can i fix it?
I want to load books from a database to a FlowLayoutPanel in a Forms app
(this part works fine), but if I enable autoscroll the scroll bar appears, but only for a split second when the library databse is loading into the flowLayoutPanel and then its not scrollable.
Here is the code that fills in the books into the flowLayoutPanel:
private Panel CreateBookPanel(Book book)
{
    Panel bookPanel = new Panel
    {
        Width = 200,
        Height = 250,
        Margin = new Padding(10),
        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
        Tag = book // Store the book object for easy retrieval
    };

    bookPanel.Click += BookPanel_Click;

    PictureBox coverPictureBox = new PictureBox
    {
        Width = 180,
        Height = 120,
        SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom,
        Dock = DockStyle.Top,
    };
    coverPictureBox.Load(book.ImageURL);
    coverPictureBox.Click += BookPanel_Click;

    Label titleLabel = new Label
    {
        Text = book.BookName,
        AutoSize = false,
        Width = bookPanel.Width,
        Height = 40,
        TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter,
        Dock = DockStyle.Top
    };
    titleLabel.Click += BookPanel_Click;

    Label authorLabel = new Label
    {
        Text = "Author: " + book.AuthorName,
        AutoSize = false,
        Width = bookPanel.Width,
        Height = 20,
        TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter,
        Dock = DockStyle.Top
    };
    authorLabel.Click += BookPanel_Click;

    bookPanel.Controls.Add(coverPictureBox);
    bookPanel.Controls.Add(titleLabel);
    bookPanel.Controls.Add(authorLabel);

    return bookPanel;
}

Screenshot of the app:

I tried adding the scroll bar separately and linking it to the flowLayoutPanel somehow, but it did not help at all.

Note: this has nothing to do with Visual Studio. Visual Studio acts only at design time, not at run time.

Maybe it helps if you set flowLayoutPanel1.AutoScroll = true; after adding a new panel. When adding or removing controls to the FlowLayoutPanel at design time manually, sometimes AutoScroll reverts to False. However, I cannot reproduce the problem at runtime when adding controls programmatically.

"Here is the code that fills in the books into the flowLayoutPanel" You haven't actually shown any code that adds the returned Panel to any FlowLayoutPanel...
